How do I cause plugin patterns to appear in the widget areas?
I'm working on a plugin that adds patterns (previously reusable blocks). How do I make these patterns appear for widget area use?

In this image I have the patterns tab open on the widget area. It is empty.

Are the blocks in your pattern individually available in widgets? I don’t think you’ll see patterns if they have blocks that can’t be used in the current context.

There are just patterns which is the tab I have open in the screenshot. I want to make them available as patterns to the widget area so they can be edited and played with to suit.

Thanks to a kind Mastodon user, I have learned that as of present, there is no answer as this is an ongoing bug/issue/thing https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/26170#issuecomment-2077758484
